# React App is only rendering index.css but not the App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, frameworks

My react app is not rendering and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, the page is just the background color. I'm able to build the app with no errors. And I'm importing all the files into App and App on index.js.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import About from './components/pages/About';
import Skills from './components/pages/Skills';
import Projects from './components/Projects';
import Resume from './components/pages/Resume';
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

const App = () => {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState('About');

    const renderPage = () => {
        if (currentPage === "About") {
            return <About />;
          }
          if (currentPage === "Skills") {
            return <Skills />;
          }
          if (currentPage === "Projects") {
            return <Projects />;
          }
          if (currentPage === "Contact") {
            return <Contact />;
          }
          return <Resume />;
        };
      
        const handlePageChange = (page) => setCurrentPage(page);
      
        return (
          <div>
            <Nav currentPage={currentPage} handlePageChange={handlePageChange} />
            <Header />
            {renderPage()}
            <Footer/>
          </div>
        );
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

index.css

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

:root {
    --color-bg: #1f1f38;
    --color-bg-v: #2c2c6c;
    --color-pr: #4db5ff;
    --color-pr-v:rgba(77,181,255,0.4);
    --color-w:white;
    --color-light: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    --container-w-lg:75%;
    --container-w-md:86%;
    --container-w-sm: 90%;
    --transition: all 400ms ease;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior:smooth;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display:none
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: var(--color-bg);
    color: var(--color-w);
    line-height: 1.7;
}

.container {
    width: var(--container-w-lg);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
    font-weight: 500;
}

h1 {
    font-size:2.5rem;
}

section {
    margin-top: 8rem;
}

section > h2, section > h5 {
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--color-light)
}

section > h2 {
    color: var(--color-pr);
    margin-bottom: 3rem;;
}

.text-light {
    color: var(--color-light);
}

a {
    color: var(--color-pr);
    transition: var(--transition);
}

a:hover {
    color: var(--color-w);
}
.btn {
    width: max-content;
    display: inline-block;
    color: var(--color-pr);
    padding: 0.75rem 1.2rem;
    border-radius:0.4rem;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-pr);
    transition: var(--transition);
}

.btn:hover {
    background: var(--color-w);
    color: var(--color-bg);
    border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-primary {
    background: var(--color-pr);
    color:var(--color-bg)
}

img{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
        width: var(--container-w-md);
    }
    section {
        margin-top: 6rem;
    }  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
        width: var(--container-w-sm);
    }
    section > h2{
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }  
}
```

I tried rewrite the functions without using arrow functions, tried to rename the files, and tried to write the content from the App into another file and import to App, cause I read it could solve my problem. But nothing worked.

Comment: Did you check if you got some errors in the devTools console?

Comment: Do you have an element in your HTML with the id of `root`

Comment: yes, there is an error "react dom client __webpack_imported_module_1__.render is not a function at ./src/index.js". I tried to fix that using this(didn’t work):

import {StrictMode} from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react- 
dom/client';

import App from './App'
const rootElement = 
document.getElementById('root');
const root = 
createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
);

Comment: I also tried this:

`import React from 'react'; import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'; import App from './App';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')); root.render(       <App /> );`

Comment: what is in index.css?

Comment: `* {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

:root {
    --color-bg: #1f1f38;
    --color-bg-v: #2c2c6c;
    --color-pr: #4db5ff;
    --color-pr-v:rgba(77,181,255,0.4);
    --color-w:white;
    --color-light: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    --container-w-lg:75%;
    --container-w-md:86%;
    --container-w-sm: 90%;
    --transition: all 400ms ease;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior:smooth;
}`

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display:none
}

Comment: `body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: var(--color-bg);
    color: var(--color-w);
    line-height: 1.7;
}

.container {
    width: var(--container-w-lg);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
    font-weight: 500;
}

h1 {
    font-size:2.5rem;
}

section {
    margin-top: 8rem;
}

section > h2, section > h5 {
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--color-light)
}

section > h2 {
    color: var(--color-pr);
    margin-bottom: 3rem;;
}

.text-light {
    color: var(--color-light);
}`

Comment: Add this CSS in the question.

Comment: You can create a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) of your code so we can try and work on it to figure out the problem.

Comment: Hi Tehila, I just figure out the problem. The Nav.js was empty and i was trying to render it. Int the past it worked, but apparently now its an issue. Anyways I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're rendering wrong, the way you do that was updated in React 18.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root"));
root.render(<App/>);
```

Comment: I did this but didn’t solve it. thanks though

Comment: @Gabriella what is the error now?

Comment: Now I have lots of errors, the first one is 
`react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at App.js:35.
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48:88)
printWarning @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87`

Comment: Did you **export** all the other components that you call in your `renderPage` function?

Comment: Yes, I did export everything

Comment: Hey, I just figure out the problem. The Nav.js was empty and i was trying to render it. Int the past it worked, but apparently now its an issue. Anyways I really appreciate the help!